# Xamarin Android Mvvmcross app crashed on MvxBootstrapRunner

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, segmentation-fault

Sometimes (1/7) my app crashes on android **4.0.4** on splash screen with **SIGSEGV** error in **MvxBootstrapRunner** class in stacktrace, and then can start after 'force stop' only.
If application crashed once endless splash screen will be displayed every next time (before force stop).
MvvmCross version **3.5.1**

```
I/mvx(15933):   0.50 Setup: MvvmCross settings start
I/mono-stdout(15933): mvx:Diagnostic:  0.50 Setup: MvvmCross settings start
I/mvx(15933):   0.50 Setup: Singleton Cache start
I/mono-stdout(15933): mvx:Diagnostic:  0.50 Setup: Singleton Cache start
I/mvx(15933):   0.52 Setup: Bootstrap actions
I/mono-stdout(15933): mvx:Diagnostic:  0.52 Setup: Bootstrap actions
I/mvx(15933):   0.54 No view model type finder available - assuming we are looking for a splash screen - returning null
I/mono-stdout(15933): mvx:Diagnostic:  0.54 No view model type finder available - assuming we are looking for a splash screen - returning null
E/mono-rt(15933): Stacktrace:
E/mono-rt(15933):   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
E/mono-rt(15933):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Type.type_is_assignable_from (System.Type,System.Type) <0xffffffff>
E/mono-rt(15933):   at System.Type.IsAssignableFrom (System.Type) <0x001c3>
E/mono-rt(15933):   at System.Reflection.TypeInfo.IsAssignableFrom (System.Reflection.TypeInfo) <0x0003b>
E/mono-rt(15933):   at Cirrious.CrossCore.ReflectionExtensions.IsAssignableFrom (System.Type,System.Type) <0x0003b>
E/mono-rt(15933):   at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxTypeExtensions/<>c__DisplayClass1a.<Inherits>b__19 (System.Type) <0x0001f>
E/mono-rt(15933):   at System.Linq.Enumerable/<CreateWhereIterator>c__Iterator1E`1.MoveNext () <0x0015b>
E/mono-rt(15933):   at Cirrious.CrossCore.Platform.MvxBootstrapRunner.Run (System.Reflection.Assembly) <0x00093>
E/mono-rt(15933):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Platform.MvxSetup.PerformBootstrapActions () <0x00063>
E/mono-rt(15933):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Platform.MvxSetup.InitializeSecondary () <0x0003b>
E/mono-rt(15933):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Platform.MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.<InitializeFromSplashScreen>b__5 (object) <0x00037>
E/mono-rt(15933):   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void__this___object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
E/mono-rt(15933): Attempting native Android stacktrace:
E/mono-rt(15933):   Could not unwind with `libunwind.so`: Cannot load library: load_library[1092]: Library '/data/data/.../lib/libunwind.so' not found
E/mono-rt(15933):   Could not unwind with `libcorkscrew.so`: Cannot load library: load_library[1092]: Library '/data/data/.../lib/libcorkscrew.so' not found
E/mono-rt(15933):   No options left to get a native stacktrace :-(
E/mono-rt(15933): =================================================================
E/mono-rt(15933): Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
E/mono-rt(15933): a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
E/mono-rt(15933): used by your application.
E/mono-rt(15933): =================================================================
A/libc(15933): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000001d (code=1)
```